# Model or ViewModel in a ListViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

Should T be a for example Customer or CustomerViewModel ?

The annotations bound to Mvc namespace are on the ListViewModel so actually I could pass the Customer object. What do you think?

```
public class ListViewModel<T>
{
        [Required(ErrorMessage="No item selected.")]
        public int[] SelectedIds { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<T> DisplayList { get; set; }        
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Open()
 {
    IEnumerable<Testplan> testplans = _testplanDataProvider.GetTestplans();
    OpenTestplanListViewModel viewModel = new OpenTestplanListViewModel(testplans);         
    return PartialView(viewModel);
 }

public class OpenTestplanListViewModel
{
        public OpenTestplanListViewModel(IEnumerable<Testplan> testplans)
        {
           var testplanViewModels = testplans.Select(t => new TestplanViewModel
           {
             Name = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", t.Release.Name, t.Template.Name, t.CreatedAt, t.CreatedBy),
              TestplanId = t.TestplanId,
           });

           DisplayList = testplanViewModels;
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "No item selected.")]
        public int[] SelectedIds { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TestplanViewModel> DisplayList { get; private set; } 
}

public class TestplanViewModel
{
        public int TestplanId { get; set; }     
        public string Name { get; set; }           
}

 public class Testplan
 {
        public int TestplanId { get; set; }
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
        public int ReleaseId { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }       
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }       
        public Template Template { get; set; }
        public Release Release { get; set; } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T` should ideally be a view model. Having a view model referencing domain models is some kind of a hybrid view model, not a real one. But if you think that in this specific case the domain model will be exactly the same as the view model then you could keep it as well.

Comment: I have updated my question with a finished code sample. I am passing a list of testplans from my database to the viewmodel`s ctor. My Testplan business object looks pretty different to my TestplanViewModel. Is there something to improve? btw. I removed the generic viewmodel.

Comment: Your OpenTestplanListViewModel view model doesn't have a default constructor. This is problematic because if you decide to use this view model as action argument it won't work because the default model binder won't know how to instantiate it. Also the setter of your `DisplayList` property is private and the default model binder won't be able to invoke it. Of course if you don't intend to use this view model as action parameter but only pass it to views there's no problem with having such custom constructor.

Comment: haha good answer. Now that you said it I remember again... I found another ViewModel with 2 constructors and I could not remember anymore why I did that...I corrected your 2 critics as the vm is generated as action param. Thanks Darin.